# Meteor {{#if}} helper if object or field exists

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am looping through documents in a template with Blaze spacebars to create a list

```
<template name="objectTemplate">
   {{#if checkIfObjectExists}}
   ({{document.[0].object.object1}})
   {{/if}}
</template>
```

I know that in some documents, some objects do not exist in that object position. normally if I didnt have (), it would be blank and I could move on, but in this case when empty, I will have a lot of () which is not good.

I created a helper, but its not working. I have tried null, 0, typeOf etc and still cant get it right. Anyhow here is the helper

```
Template.objectTemplate.helper ({ 
checkIfObjectExists: function() { 
 if (this !== 'null') {
  return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
});`
```

Comment: Give us more code. From what I can see here, you are testing if the template is null (this would be the template).

Comment: thanks. I clearly stated the code below was a template helper, but it could never hurt to add more clarity.

Comment: I really meant "more code". When is "objectTemplate" called. But I'll do the answer.

Comment: @MatthiasEckhart please post your answer as answer so I can mark it correct. I fixed the issue after playing around with it and learning underscore. I used _isObject instead but the main issue was document[0] which you corrected and I did not notice the corrections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[`_.has(object, key)`](http://underscorejs.org/#has)** if you want to check if the object `document.[0].object` has the property `object1` set. The function **[`_.isObject(value)`](http://underscorejs.org/#isObject)** will check instead if `document.[0].object.object1` is an `Object` (this also includes arrays).

So, depending on your requirements, your template helpers should look like this:

```
Template.objectTemplate.helper({
    checkIfObjectPropertyExists: function() {
        return _.has(this.document[0].object, "object1");
    },
    checkIfPropertyIsObject: function() {
        return _.isObject(this.document.[0].object.object1);
    }
});
```

---

You could also register an [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org) global template helper and then use it directly in your Meteor templates:

```
Template.registerHelper('_', function () {
    return _;
});
```

---

```
<template name="objectTemplate">
   {{#if _.has this.document.[0].object 'object1'}}
      ({{document.[0].object.object1}})
   {{/if}}
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you Matthias. This answer was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` is not in the right place. Your `objectTemplate` is probably called that way :

```
{{#each datum in data}}
    {{>objectTemplate data=data}}
{{/each}}
```

So it's always rendered. Even if the datum is empty. The `this` you check in your helper will always be true, it's the template himself.

So, you should call it that way :

```
{{#each datum in data}}
    {{#if datum.thingToTest}}
        {{>objectTemplate datum=datum}}
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

The entire sub template won't be called.

Comment: Thank you. The objectTemplate is being called into another template that is iterating with {{#each}}. When the object1 from {{document.[0].object.object1}} exists the values show up. Everything works except. I have those parentheses "()" that are not dynamic so I wanted to build a if statement that would display results if existed and nothing if not.